# AS400 Job's Thread details

Tags: java, multithreading, ibm-midrange, jt400

I've already been retrieved details of a specific AS/400 job by its job number. I have a problem. I want to get that specific jobs thread detail. Some jobs have multi threading. I need to get specific job's list of multi threads and thread details. I'm checked jt400 doc for finding some class for it. But I'm failing to find :(

Thank in Advance!

```
JobList jobList = new JobList(System);

jobList.clearJobSelectionCriteria();
jobList.addJobSelectionCriteria(JobList.SELECTION_JOB_NUMBER, jobNumber);

Enumeration list = jobList.getJobs();
while (list.hasMoreElements()) {
Job j = (Job) list.nextElement();

System.out.println(j.getName());
System.out.println(j.getStatus());
System.out.println(j.getOutputQueue());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API you're looking for is [QWCOLTHD](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/apis/qwcolthd.htm).  JTOpen 8.1 was recently released and I don't see the QWCOLTHD API implemented.

It looks like you either need to email the developers and ask for this API, or write the implementation yourself.  JTOpen is open source; you can get the source code and see how similar APIs are implemented and then write the appropriate classes for QWCOLTHD.

Comment: Thank you sir :) Now i can undestand. Thanks again!